# Jupyter Notebook kernel dies when I increase the number of samples

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to execute the following python code:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(9,6))  
plt.title("Dendrograms for number of clusters")  
dend = sch.dendrogram(sch.linkage(scaled, method='ward'))
```

When I execute the above code with 12000 samples it works fine. However, when I increase the samples to 24000 it shows that `Kernel appears to be dead` in Jupyter notebook. [KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5), keep random ports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oznEP.png) Any help is really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue with scipy package. I downgraded the package scipy from `1.7.3 to 1.7.1` and it is working. However, the downgraded version of `scipy` has an issue of `maximum recursion depth exceeded while getting str of an object`. The second issue can be resolved by expanding the limit.